# Wordpress add_meta_box wrapped in div?

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently finishing up a wordpress plugin that' I've been writting..

My question is: I'm adding some add_meta_box stuff() for the admin panel option, is there anyways I can wrap the output of add_meta_box() into a div?

Example:

```
<div id="meta_wrapper_here">
<?php example_meta_boxes() ?> content here..
</div>




<?php
function create_transcript() {
register_post_type( 'example',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Plugin-Example',
            'singular_name' => 'Plugin-Example',
            'add_new' => 'Add New',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Plugin-Example Set',
            'edit' => 'Edit',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Plugin-Example Set',
            'new_item' => 'New Plugin-Example Set',
            'view' => '',
            'view_item' => '',
            'search_items' => 'Search Plugin-Example Sets',
            'not_found' => 'No Plugin-Example Sets found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Plugin-Example Sets found in Trash',
            'parent' => 'Parent Example'
        ),

        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array( 'title' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'example_meta_boxes', // Callback function for custom metaboxes
        'has_archive' => true
    )
);

}

add_action( 'init', 'create_transcript' );

function example_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'example_form', 'Set Details', 'example_form', 'example', 'normal', 'high' );
}
?>
```

Comment: I hope you don't have that `#meta_wrapper_here` hanging alone in the middle of the plugin's code... Much probably, the answer is ***no***, WP outputs the meta boxes inside its markup and you're limited to the inner contents. Why do you need that?

Comment: thanks the reply.. I wrote several features and wrapped them into a tabbed interface, but I can't get the metabox stuff inside my tabbed interface.

Comment: A tabbed interface *inside* the CPT editing screen? Is that a super-meta-box? I cannot visualize what you're trying to do. If possible, add more details to the Question itself: [edit].